# Calculating mutiple element widths & subtracting them on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to calculate the widths of each span element with class name `alt`, subtract that width and then subtract a further 50px from that calculation:

```
<ul class="items">
    <li class="product1 alt"><a href=""><span>Televisions</span></a></li>
    <li class="product2"><a href=""><span>MP3 Players</span></a></li>
    <li class="product3 alt"><a href=""><span>Speakers</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery:

```
function moveIt() {
    var diamond = $("#ir-content li.alt a span").width();
    $("#ir-content li.alt a span").css("left","-" + theMath - "50px");
    alert(theMath);
}

moveIt();
```

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rxw3B/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
function moveIt(){
    $("#ir-content li.alt a span").each(function(){
        $(this).css("left", ((0 - $(this).width()) - 50) + "px")
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    moveIt();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxw3B/8/

Note, in this answer, the above actually worked with the OP's markup and css. However, this is probably a better example for posterity (using `position: relative`):

http://jsfiddle.net/rxw3B/9/

Comment: Thanks. This works great where there is only one "alt" class. But if there are multiple span's with "alt" class, it appears they all get added together?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish. It seemed as if you were wanting to calculate all of the widths of the `span`s, then offset them to the left. Is this not right? My example does actually work on more than one `li.alt a span`, but you have to view it in jsffidle (and no `span` has an `alt` class, btw).

Comment: Right, your example works great in that it calculates all of the spans and adds them together. I am attempting to calculate the width of each span independently. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxw3B/5/. See how it adds both .alt span widths? i'm trying to have it so it would calculate each .alt span is 200px and move it 200px for each one.

Comment: So you want to find the [widest `span`](http://jsfiddle.net/rxw3B/6/) and set that to be the offset?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5949/discussion-between-yahreen-and-jared-farrish)

Comment: @AdamRackis - See the solution and the chat session if you're interested.